# Spring MVC Forms - Retrieve a list of beans or strings from multiple values?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I will prefix this with the fact that I am new to Spring.

I have a list of beans off of a backing bean which I am using to create a form with checkboxes. Is it possible, after submitting this form to have the same list of beans populated only with the beans that the user has checked?

I am running into problems with this approach and I know I could set it up to get the ID attribute for these beans as a list of Strings but I would ideally like to have it populate a list of the same type of beans (I'm just not sure if Spring forms work this way).

I think adding code might convolute my question but here is the basics of what I am working with:

When Java gets to my controller code, should myBackingBean have a list of myGenericBeans that were selected via checkbox? What am I missing?

Java

```
class MyBackingBean
{
    List<MyGenericBean> myGenericBeans;
    public function getMyGenericBeans()
    {
        return myGenericBeans;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<form:form action="/path/formHandler" commandName="myBackingBean" class="popup-form">
    <form:checkboxes path="myGenericBeans" items="${myBackingBean.myGenericBeans}" />
</form:form>
```

Java (controller code)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/formHandler", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editAccountTeam(@ModelAttribute("myBackingBean") MyBackingBean myBackingBean, BindingResult result) {

    ...

    return "";
}
```

Comment: Can you share some code to make this clearer?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you are going to be able to do is generate a list of bean names that is used as the value of the check boxes.  Then when the user submits the page, build a list of selected beans (from the check boxes) and get the beans from your application context (i.e. `getBean("bean name");`)